# The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. AngularJs MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm unable to pass the RequestVerificationToken from webpage to server using AngularJs.

My AngularJs Code is:

```
var app = angular.module('validation', []);
app.controller('SignUpController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.email = {};
    $scope.sendEmail = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Contact/Test',
            data: $scope.email,
            headers: {
                'RequestVerificationToken': $scope.antiForgeryToken
            }
        }).success();
    };
});
```

Custom Attribute Code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class CustomAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {


        private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            string cookieToken = String.Empty;
            string formToken = String.Empty;
            string tokenValue = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
            {
                string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(':');
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                    formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                }
            }
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            try
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    ValidateRequestHeader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request);
                }
                else
                {
                    AntiForgery.Validate();
                }
            }
            catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
            {
                throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Anti forgery token cookie not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Form is:

```
@functions{
    public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
    }
}
<div ng-app="validation" ng-controller="SignUpController">
    <form role="form" id="frmContact" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")" method="POST">
        <input id="antiForgeryToken" ng-model="antiForgeryToken" type="hidden" ng-init="antiForgeryToken='@GetAntiForgeryToken()'" />
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmailTitle)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailTitle, new { placeholder = @Resource.EmailTitle, @class = "form-control", data_ng_model = "new.email.title" })
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress, new { placeholder = @Resource.EmailAddress, @class = "form-control", data_ng_model = "new.email.address" })
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmailMessage)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.EmailMessage, new { placeholder = @Resource.EmailMessage, @class = "form-control", data_ng_model = "new.email.message" })
        </fieldset>


        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="btnEmailForm" id="btnEmailForm" class="btnLogin" ng-click="sendEmail()" value="sendMessage">@Resource.ContactFormSendMessageButton</button>
        </div>
        <div id="errorMessages" class="error">{{message}}</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have read the following posts, but cannot seem to solve the problem, and also took code from https://github.com/techbrij/angularjs-asp-net-mvc which works in that example but not in my MVC application:

http://techbrij.com/angularjs-antiforgerytoken-asp-net-mvc

https://parthivpandya.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/angularjs-and-antiforgerytoken-in-asp-net-mvc/

[AngularJS Web Api AntiForgeryToken CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460196/angularjs-web-api-antiforgerytoken-csrf)

http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/angularjs-and-aspnet-mvc-isajaxrequest.html

[Where exactly to put the antiforgeryToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780958/where-exactly-to-put-the-antiforgerytoken)

http://www.ojdevelops.com/2016/01/using-antiforgerytokens-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Can anyone help with this problem

Comment: Not clear: on btnEmailForm click you want to send your form to Index/Contact and simultaneously perform post request to /Contact/Test? And your custom attribute: `CustomAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` on which of this actions it applied? And also antiForgeryToken input not has attribute `name= '__RequestVerificationToken'` that is why it not goes to server.

Comment: My mistake, getting frustrated as unable to solve this problem Index/Contact should be /Contact/Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this case you perform form `submit` and `$scope.sendEmail` operations and they may conflict one with another, to prevent this behavior you can use `ng-submit` directive. And also add attributes: `name= '__RequestVerificationToken'` and `ng-value="antiForgeryToken"` to corresponding `input`.

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** Default behavior of `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` expects `__RequestVerificationToken` token in form values. To send request to server in form values format one requires `content-type` to be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But I didn't have this option unfortunately and my content-type was `application/json`. Hence I took this custom path.

Let me explain the approach I took which worked.

Step 1: Declare `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your view (.cshtml) as shown below:

```
<form id="inputForm" name="inputForm" ng-submit="submit(broker)" novalidate>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        /* other controls of form */
</form>
```

Step 2: `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` will render an hidden field which will hold the token value as:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="GvTcz2tTgHOS2KK_7jpHvPWEJPcbJmHIpSAlxY1">
```

Step 3: Create custom attribute for Anti-forgery token verification as

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]    
public class HbValidateAntiForgeryToken : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IExceptionFilter    
{    
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var antiForgeryCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
            AntiForgery.Validate(antiForgeryCookie != null ? antiForgeryCookie.Value : null,
                filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw new SecurityException("Unauthorised access detected and blocked");
        }
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception != null &&
            filterContext.Exception is System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            // Handle error page scenario here
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4: Declare the above attribute wherever required (Only on HttpPost methods of controller. DO NOT declare on HttpGet)

```
[HttpPost]
[HbValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult IsUsernameExists(string username)
{
}
```

Step 5: In AngularJS, in factory pass `__RequestVerificationToken` as header.

```
hbServices.factory('RegistrationService', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource(applicationPath + 'api/MyUserMembership/:dest', {}, {
        createNewUser: { method: 'POST', isArray: false, params: { dest: 'CreateNewUser' }, 
                         headers: { 
                             '__RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                            }
                        },
        isUsernameExists: { method: 'POST', isArray: false, params: { dest: 'IsUsernameExists' }, 
        headers: { 
            '__RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
           }
       }
    });
}]);
```

Please note the way I am passing value of `__RequestVerificationToken` read from hidden field that was rendered by ASP.NET MVC's `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

**My application was using jquery and has reference of jquery already so reading the value was easy. You can try other methods to read this value**

**Summary**
The `AntiForgery.Validate()` does the magic of validating the value of forgery token here and is wonderful so far. Hope this helps!